# How to Set the margin of RDLC Report Before saving it to disc in PDF Format?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, reportviewer

I'm trying to save RDLC report to Disc in PDF Format using this code.

```
    this.RequestViewer.SetPageSettings(Utility.Generate_Window_Control.funcSetReportMargin());
        byte[] bytes = RequestViewer.LocalReport.Render(

            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {

            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
```

and setting the margin of report page using this function

```
    public static System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings funcSetReportMargin()
   {
       System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
       pg.Margins.Top = 10;
       pg.Margins.Bottom = 10;
       pg.Margins.Left = 0;
       pg.Margins.Right = 0;
       return pg;
   }
```

this function is working fine in PrintPreview but when I save it to pdf it prints blank pages. Kindly guide me how can i do it.